# Custom Header won't Repeat

Tags: headers

I have tried everything I can think of to get my custom header to simply repeat horizontally. [Here](http://www.playfulsstudio.com) is the website.

If you zoom the page out you can see what I mean. The top black bar does, and the menu does because the 100% width parameter works, but the header will not. The code is changing by the minute because I am in the process of trying all sorts of crazy coding. But this is the jist of what is in my Header, Functions, and Css. I cannot get the header to accept repeat-x.

http://pastebin.com/aAEN2pmu

Comment: Do not use pastebin. Add your code in your question through an [edit]. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are targeting `#header img`(incorrect) and using `repeat-x` without any background-image property.

Use this CSS code:

```
#header {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("http://playfulsstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/cropped-playful-logo.jpg") repeat-x scroll 0 0;
}
```

Comment: The only way I can fix this is by adding the 100% attribute and it distorts the header instead of repeating it. Your code still will not make it repeat. Why is it not listening? Help.

Comment: Changed the pastebin above to reflect the actual code I am using right now. As you can see it does not repeat and remains fixed unlike the rest of the page causing a long horizontal scroll into oblivion to the right. Please someone help.

Comment: Ok. For now I have added a overflow:hidden rule and it has fixed the scrolling but the header still won't repeat-x. Why?

Comment: Yay. It worked. I just needed to set the width back to 100% and add a overflow:hidden value. Thank you!

Comment: Glad that worked :) Please don't use Pastebin next time. I could not view the code.